# Produce a confidence interval contour plot for a linear fit (with two parameters) in Python

Tags: confidence-interval, data-visualization, chi-squared-test, least-squares

I  would like to produce a confidence interval contour plot in Python based on a least-squares linear fit to an arbitrary set of data. I apply the polyfit function for a linear fit (i.e. y = mx + c) weighted by errors on arrays of x, y, yerr, and obtain the minimum chi square value and the coefficients of the linear fit to which it corresponds.

From this point, I am at a loss as to how to plot the ellipse for a 1 sigma deviation from the optimal coefficient values. I want to plot c on the x-axis and m on the y-axis, and a single 1 sigma contour. I keep thinking I need to find an inverse to the chi square function (defined in the code explicitly), but this doesn't make sense logically.

Ultimately, I need an ellipse of the form chi^2(m, c) = chi^2_min + 1. Any ideas what tools I need to use?

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set of x,y values (with y errors) to which a linear fit will be applied
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([1.7, 2.1, 3.5, 3.2, 4.4])
erry = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3])

# apply fit to x,y array weighted by 1/erry^2
p2, V = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, w=1/erry, cov=True)

# define a chi square function into which parameter estimates are passed
def chisq(param1, param0):
    csq = np.sum(((param1*x + param0 - y)/erry) ** 2)
    return csq

# arrange labels for the coefficients so matches form y = theta1*x + theta0
theta1 = p2[0]
theta0 = p2[1]
# show coeffs with corresponding stat errors
print("a1 = ",theta1,"+-",np.sqrt(V[0][0]))
print("a0 = ",theta0,"+-",np.sqrt(V[1][1]))

# define arrays for the parameters running between (arbitrarily) parameter +/- 0.3
run1 = np.array([theta1-0.3, theta1-0.2, theta1-0.1, theta1, theta1+0.1, theta1+0.2, theta1+0.3])
run0 = np.array([theta0-0.3, theta0-0.2, theta0-0.1, theta0, theta0+0.1, theta0+0.2, theta0+0.3])

# define the minimum chi square value readily
chisqmin = chisq(run1[4],run0[4])

# Would like to produce a contour at one sigma from min chi square value,
# i.e. obeys ellipse eqn. chi^2(theta0, theta1) = chisqmin + 1

# add lines one sigma away from the optimal parameter values that yield the min chi square value
plt.axvline(x=theta0+np.sqrt(V[1][1]),color='k',linestyle='--')
plt.axvline(x=theta0-np.sqrt(V[1][1]),color='k',linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(y=theta1+np.sqrt(V[0][0]),color='k',linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(y=theta1-np.sqrt(V[0][0]),color='k',linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta_{0}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\theta_{1}$')
```
````

Answer (score 1):

It's not a satisfying solution, but I've brute-forced the ellipse using matplotlib.patches

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import math

# set of x,y values (with y errors) to which a linear fit will be applied
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([1.7, 2.1, 3.5, 3.2, 4.4])
erry = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3])
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# apply fit to x,y array weighted by 1/erry^2
p2, V = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, w=1/erry, cov=True)

# define a chi square function into which parameter estimates are passed
def chisq(param1, param0):
    csq = np.sum(((param1*x + param0 - y)/erry) ** 2)
    return csq

# arrange labels for the coefficients so matches form y = theta1*x + theta0
theta1 = p2[0]
theta0 = p2[1]
# show coeffs with corresponding stat errors
print("a1 = ",theta1,"+-",np.sqrt(V[0][0]))
print("a0 = ",theta0,"+-",np.sqrt(V[1][1]))

# define arrays for the parameters running between +/- sigma
run1 = np.linspace(theta1 - np.sqrt(V[0][0]), theta1 + np.sqrt(V[0][0]))
run0 = np.linspace(theta0 - np.sqrt(V[1][1]), theta0 + np.sqrt(V[1][1]))

# define the minimum chi square value readily
chisqmin = chisq(theta0, theta1)
print(chisqmin)

# Would like to produce a contour at one sigma from min chi square value,
# i.e. obeys ellipse eqn. chi^2(theta0, theta1) = chisqmin + 1


# add lines one sigma away from the optimal parameter values that yield the min chi square value
plt.axvline(x=theta0+np.sqrt(V[1][1]),color='k',linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8)
plt.axvline(x=theta0-np.sqrt(V[1][1]),color='k',linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8)
plt.axhline(y=theta1+np.sqrt(V[0][0]),color='k',linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8)
plt.axhline(y=theta1-np.sqrt(V[0][0]),color='k',linestyle='--', linewidth=0.8)
plt.plot(theta0, theta1, 'o', markersize=4, color='k')
plt.annotate(r'LS estimate',
            xy=(theta0, theta1), xytext=(-80, -40), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=14,
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.2"))
plt.annotate(r'$\chi^{2}(\theta_{0}, \theta_{1})$ = $\chi^{2}_{min}$ + 1',
            xy=(1.2, 0.7), xytext=(-22, +30), textcoords='offset points', fontsize=14,
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.2"))
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta_{0}$', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(r'$\theta_{1}$', fontsize=16)
plt.xlim(theta0-2*np.sqrt(V[1][1]), theta0+2*np.sqrt(V[1][1]))
plt.ylim(theta1-2*np.sqrt(V[0][0]), theta1+2*np.sqrt(V[0][0]))

sig0 = np.sqrt(V[1][1])
sig1 = np.sqrt(V[0][0])
rho = V[0][1]/(sig1*sig0)
tantwophi = 2*rho*sig1*sig0/(sig0**2-sig1**2)
twophi = math.atan(tantwophi)
phi = twophi/2
phideg = math.degrees(phi)


ellipse=Ellipse((theta0, theta1), width=2.1*np.sqrt(V[1][1]), 
                height=0.8*np.sqrt(V[0][0]), angle=phideg, color='k', ls='-', lw=1.5, fill=False)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
```